# Is a category a conglomerate?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

In the book *The joy of cats*, a category is defined as a tuple $(\mathcal O, \text{Hom}, \text{id}, \circ)$, where $\mathcal O$ is a class, etc. So a category consists of a class and a few "functions" between classes. Since classes can't contain classes, this means that a category must be a conglomerate, right?

And if we wanted to talk about a "bigger category" like the "category" of all categories, we would need some concept bigger than a conglomerate right? What concept would this be?

Comment: The *collection* of all (large) categories may form a conglomerate (in some foundation), but a single category is a structured class: you don't need a larger notion of collection than class to talk about a single category.

Comment: @varkor what does it mean for a class to be "structured"?

Comment: As in: you have class along with operations on the class (such as partial operations taking each pair of composable morphisms to their composite, and so on). So you need to be able to describe classes and functions between classes, but not collections of classes.